# Rotate image to point

Tags: objective-c, ios4, image-rotation

I have the following:

```
CGPoint pos //center of an image
CGPoint target //a point, somewhere in the coordinate system
float rotation //the current rotation of the image to the x-axis, clockwise, so "right" would be 90°
```

Now I want the image to rotate around it's centerpoint (pos) so that it looks directly towards the targetpoint.

My idea was: Calculate the angle corresponding to the x-axis, subtract rotation, and then rotate it.

Two things:

1.) I fail at calculating the angle. (Yes, I know it's all in rad...)

2.) What's best for rotating?

- CGAffineTransform? But then I'd need an imageView
- Or: save context, set origin to center of image, rotate context, draw image, restore context? More complicated, but no imageview neeeded...

Answer (score 0):

Draw it on a CALayer, and move the layer around anyway you like.

Comment: Ok, i made that... could you please help me with that CALayer stuff? I have my image and need to rotate it x rad....